# syntax error, unexpected ',' in view, but no ',' iin view file

Tags: php-7, laravel-5.8

I am getting the error

```
syntax error, unexpected ',' (View: /home/vagrant/code/JCSE/resources/views/comments/caConfirm.blade.php)
```

when I view the following blade file:

```
@extends{'templates.layout')
@section('title')
    Comment Submitted
@endsection
@section('content')
    @lang('comments.CA_CONFIRM')
    @lang('jrnl.ADMIN_SIG')
@endsection
```

You will see that there is no ',' in the view, so I am at a loss to understand what the problem is. The error still occurs with completely empty sections.
I get the error when I call the view directly from a route:

```
Route::get('/caConfirmTest', function(){return view('comments.caConfirm');});
```

The usual template file is rather large, but doesn't give errors with any other views, and the view still gives the error with a minimal template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>
        @yield('title')
        @section('title')
            {{ config('jrnl.shortName') }}
        @endsection
    </title>
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

Any help welcome!

**EDIT**

Following morph's suggestion, the error in the compiled view seems to come after the @endsection directive, with the last of the following lines being highlighted:

```
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>

<?php echo $__env->make(, \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), ['__data', '__path']))->render(); ?><?php /**PATH /home/vagrant/code/JCSE/resources/views/comments/caConfirm.blade.php ENDPATH**/ ?>
```

The $__env->make(, looks suspicious, but I have not been able to track down what this implies.

Comment: Best bet is to look at the compiled blade files, which I'm guessing your error will point you to. I believe they end up in `storage/framework/views`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion morph - it's got me a bit further (see my edit), but I'm still stuck ...

Comment: You have a typo: `@extends{'templates.layout')` - the first curly brace should be a normal bracket. I tried in a Laravel project and confirmed that typo will cause the error msg you are seeing.

Comment: Many thanks - I do find it difficult to tell the difference between { and ( on my display, but I should have seen that sooner! At least I know what to look for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Typo mistake in blade syntax

```
Change this 

@extends{'templates.layout')

to this

@extends('templates.layout')
```